# How to make Schedule tweet from blackberry application

Tags: blackberry, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am integrating twitter in my Blackberry application. I can `Tweet` from my application. But now i want to `schedule the tweet` i.e i want to set time when time comes it will automatically tweet. I am using `RestApi of Twitter`.I have authenticate my application by **OAuth 1.0**. Does any body did this

Please help thanks

**UPDATE**

Actually as `Jprofitt` said that i need to schedule my App with the help of `ApplicationManager` but my situation is

> I made a `class` which extends `MainScreen` Class for doing `Tweet`.
>    So what i want to do is  to call this class after setting the time but dont get any clear Idea can any body please look at it and advice me some Solution. While i was searching for `ApplicationManager` i have seen that there is a class which extend `Application` so i am confused can any body help me out from this

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see no reason why you wouldn't be able to do this. All you need to do is get the user authenticated once so you have all of the tokens needed to send a Tweet. After that just use the `ApplicationManager` to schedule your app to run with an alternate entry point that directs it to send the Tweets it has queued up to send.

Some sample code:

```
ApplicationManager appMan = ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager();
ApplicationDescriptor myApp = ApplicationDescriptor.currentApplicationDescriptor();

if(appMan.scheduleApplication(myApp, timeToRunApp, true)) {
    //scheduled to run, do something if you need to
}
else{
    //failed to schedule, do something else
}
```

If you want to pass arguments for an alternate entry point, change your ApplicationDescriptor to
`ApplicationDescriptor myApp = new ApplicationDescriptor(ApplicationDescriptor.currentApplicationDescriptor(), new String[]{"arg1"});`

Comment: ok will work on that ..... thanks for the suggestion and if it works i will accept it as an answer thanks again..

Comment: one confusion i have. I made an application in which i made a screen for doing tweet. can you elaborate more how can i do it . Because i have never implemented Application manager thanks

Comment: I have scheduled an app to run every minute, however everytime it attempts to access the internet it keeps timing out, at least this happens from the simulator.